# Visual Studio very slow with C++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I am new to C++ programming and have been setting up Unreal Engine 4 with Visual Studio 2019.
The problem I am facing is that VS seems very slow to recognize my code in C++.
For example, it can take more than 10 seconds to recognize that I wrote a method declaration and apply the proper color and give me intellisense (intellicode?) or show me any error. Same problem with variables and such. Code completion is pretty much never happening.

It's unusable right now and I would appreciate if somebody have an idea of what's going on.

I never have this problem in C#.
I tried activate / deactivate extensions (just got a couple of them). I have ran a VS repair.
I have a recent computer (i7 9k, 16gb RAM) running windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible due to antivirus software scanning in the background? Can you just try to turn it off temporarily to see if things getting better? If so, please consider ignore paths related to C++ compiler and your code folders in the antivirus software.

Comment: Unfortunately, turning of the antivirus doesn't seem to change anything. My problem seems to be specific with source files in relation with Unreal Engine 4. If I create an empty new project and start coding some C++, VS is as snappy as usual.